# How to Read / Write or Preserve Fragment Identifiers on Post-back

Tags: asp.net, postback, fragment-identifier

I'm using fragment identifiers to run a tabbed browsing control and it would be nice if the post-back could preserve the tab as that is less jarring to the user. To that end I've been searching for a method to preserve the fragment identifier and am at a total loss.

Is there a way to read or save the fragment identifier from the referring url during a page post-back in ASP.NET?

Comment: how u implemented this is asp.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save/retrieve URL fragments on the server side because Browsers don't send them -and they aren't supposed to- to the server. [See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a local application (see below) fragments do not participate in HTTP redirections.

Comment: @Harie - you cannot implement this. It doesn't get sent to the server. There is nothing to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.location.hash` from javascript to read the fragment. You can use this to send something to the server in the POST, and then the server could include it in a 30x redirect.